# UI/Canvas appears in front of objects, even though it's set to World Space

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

In my Google Cardboard project, I have several canvases attached to walls in a room. These canvases have buttons the player can interact with. I set each canvas to World Space, but for some reason, the buttons are rendering in front of objects that should appear in front of the buttons.

update1:
The UI appears behind the cube in the game and scene windows when not running. It's only when I hit play that the image appears in front of the cube. I am adding images to the UI button programatically, but the problem happens even if I add images only using the editor.

update2:
If I disable the cardboard elements in my scene (i.e. use a standard fps camera setup), I do not get the issue.

Picture below: Checkerboard is UI. Gray block is 3D block. I want UI behind the block, on the wall.

[image: checkerboard should appear behind the block]

[image: canvas object]

[image]

Comment: From this screenshot, I can't tell what is UI and what is 3D object.

Comment: Where do you want the UI to be?

Comment: Behind the gray cube, on the wall

Comment: Disable VR Mode from GVRViewer component and please post more screenshots from canvas component inspector, and object inspector. Information you provided is not enough for anyone to help you.

Comment: Okay, I will post more information later today. Thanks

Comment: Additional screenshots posted. The inspector shows a canvas object and a UI Button called painting.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in Unity 5.4.3f1 using the GVR SDK 1.0. The problem only occurs in the editor, not in Android builds. Are you also experiencing the problem in builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on answers.unity3D made this suggestions:

> The problem may come from the shader used by the UI element with a
>   ZTest value set to Off or the Queue tag of the UI element's shader is
>   "higher" than the tag of the cube's shader

Turns out, and this is apparent in the 3rd screenshot, my UI buttons did not have a material. Once I provided one, I used one that used a standard UI shader (I initially tried unlit, but that made them disappear).

I guess there are still some issues with shaders and google cardboard. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Manually move the parent UI object behind the gray object.

[image]

Comment: Hahah I wish it was that easy. The parent UI object IS behind the cube. I should add, the UI appears behind the cube in the game and scene windows when not running. It's only when I hit play that the image appears in front of the cube. Also, I am adding images to the UI programatically, I guess that's probably where I should look.

Comment: It's a runtime result. Testing on for PC not cardborad though. But it should be similar. Instantiated UI objects seems to take place near origin unless position modified. Runtime image assignment may not be an issue

Comment: Ah, you are having issue in editor too. Mine working fine though. Do you think Unity version issue. Using 5.2.4f1.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if it's a version issue or not. I'm using 5.4.0f3. I will see if I get the issue without the cardboard camera, etc.

Comment: And I've moved the canvases my UI buttons are embedded in from the origin, so I don't think that should be the issue.